# A big query, String in C

Tags: c, printf

A colleague was trying to teach me something but he failed. I cannot understand what he is talking about.

I am being given string1 and string2 but also a (int)number.

I have to compare a number of characters, specified by user input, of both strings and display the bigger substring. 
He does this because someone else showed him how to do it.

```
if (result > 0) {
    printf("sub-string1 \'%.*s\' is bigger\n\n", number, string1);
}
else if (result < 0) {
    printf("sub-string2 \'%.*s\' is bigger\n\n", number, string2);
}
else { //if result == 0
    printf("Both sub-strings \'%.*s\' and \'%.*s\' are equal\n\n", number, string1, number, string2);
}
```

My question is, What does this mean? Please be explicit as if you were talking to my grandma. She does not understand computers at all. 
So what is this:

```
\'%.*s\'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) has a pretty good explanation of what that modifier means. (The `\'` is not part of the modifier, it is a literal '  in the printed text)

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape single quote in strings.

Comment: I see...I will post the whole software here when i am done..It might help others as it is everything we've done on strings once ready.

Comment: Where did the value of `result` come from?

Answer (score 0):

The `\'%.*s\'` means it will be replaced by a string of text specified by `string1`, which has a character length of `number`.

More explanation on the symbols:

```
\' simply means '
% means whatever follows it will be replaced by what you provided
. indicates what follows it is a number, which specifies the length of the string(only in the case of string)
* means it will be replaced by a numerical variable (here number)
s means it will be replaced by a string
```

Hope it helps